# Inserting Excel sheet into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, data-import

I am trying to insert an Excel sheet into a SQL Server database from datagridview using OleDb.

The code that I use :

```
namespace importfromexcel
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMNDOSH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial    Catalog=mohammed;Integrated Security=True");
  //  SqlCommand cmd;

     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + ofd.FileName + @";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        // Create Connection to Excel Workbook

        //We can Import excel to sql server like this
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select fname,lname FROM [sheet1$]", connection);

            connection.Open();

            // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet 
            using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // SQL Server Connection String 
                string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=HAMNDOSH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mohammed;Integrated Security=True";
                //  SqlCommand cmd;

                // Bulk Copy to SQL Server 
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "test";
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My database name is : `mohammed` and the table name is `test` with two columns `firstname` and `lastname` and the Excel sheet columns is `fname` and `lname` ..

The problem is that when I execute the code and after insert the Excel sheet from button2 
when I click button1 and I got an window error

> *vshot32-clr2.exe has stopped working*

Any help please ??

Comment: is this something you want your users to do or just you? If it's just for you then use the management studio to import the sheet. Much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the root cause, but you're referencing `ofd.FileName` in your `Click` event when there's no guarantee that the dialog has a valid file selected.  Since you're storing that value in a text box I would change it to:

```
string excelConnectionString = 
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" 
          + textBox1.Text 
          + @";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
```

I would also verify that you're able to *query* the data (e.g. by writing to a text file) as a test before trying to implement bulk copy.  Also be aware that the source data must have exactly the same structure (including column order) unless you supply a [`ColumnMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sql server has a import tool called Sql Server Data Tools... there you can find a activity to import from a excel file... very "end-user" deal, by that i mean the you can configure everything on drag and drop basis...

Answer (score 0):

In your extended properties for the excel connection string, you may wish to set HDR=YES and IMEX=1. HDR=YES will read the first row in your excel sheet and read the data stored in each cell as a column name. IMEX=1 tells JET to insert the data regardless of datatype from each cell.

Have a look at this code I have written myself, it may help you.

```
        //ExcelDA Class
        public ExcelDA()
    {
        connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + ofd.FileName + "; Extended Properties=" + '"' + "Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1" + '"';
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to retrieve a datatable from excel sheet
    /// </summary>
    public DataTable GetProductsExcel()
    {
        StringBuilder excBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        excBuilder.Append("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$];");
        //
        try
        {
            return ExecuteSqlStatement(excBuilder.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Error retreiving data");
            return null;
        }
    }
    private DataTable ExecuteSqlStatement(string command)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, conn))
                {
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    adaptor.Fill(table);
                    return table;
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    //SqlDA class
    public void ExecuteSQLCommand(string comm)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comm, conn))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) { throw ex; }
    }
    public void AddNames(string fName, string sName)
    {
          StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
          //build sql insert statement here
          ExecuteSQLCommand(sqlBuilder.ToString());
    }

    //Program class
    ExcelDA reader = new ExcelDA();
    DataTable names = reader.GetSuppliersExcel();
    //string array to store excel row data for names
    string[] arr2 = new string[2] { "", ""};
        //recursive loop to retrieve each row and values from each rows columns
        foreach (DataRow row in suppliers.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == (names.Columns.Count - 1))
                {
                    arr2[i] = (row[i].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    arr2[i] = (row[i].ToString());
                }
            }
        }

            try
            {
                sql.AddNames(arr2[0], arr2[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("Added Data to SQL");
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
```

Comment: thanks for your help , but the same error is shown to me every time i debug